# ASP.Net Request Life Cycle - Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have a image file in my sample Project. I am trying the URL as below.

> http://localhost:49334/Chrysanthemum.jpg

I have a `Application_BeginRequest event` in my `Global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

**Query** - This event is not getting fired when I request the above image by directly typing the URL above.

---

**[FROM MSDN - HttpApplication.BeginRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx)** - Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

```
I want to make my all request to fire `Application_BeginRequest` Event
```

Comment: Check you really are using IIS7 with an integrated app pool.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably because .jpg extension is not defaultly mapped to asp.net and is handled by IIS.

If you using IIS7 you can change this by set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true.

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  ...
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

If still this event is not fired, you can try change global.asax like this

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    public override void Init()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(global_asax_BeginRequest);        
        base.Init();
    }

    void global_asax_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }    

</script>
```

If you want handle only .jpg files, better way is to make HTTP handler and configure **system.webServer > handlers** and **system.web > httpHandlers** section in web.config to run this handler for .jpg requests.

Comment: Can you tell something about the PitFalls of setting this code in Web.Config ?

Comment: What pitfalls? If you want to know more about handlers, see this url: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Comment: Thanks for the link but This link is not explicitly clarifying about the pitfalls of using `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">`

Comment: ok, see this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-modules-overview/#Precondition